# How can enjambment be used to enhance rhythm in a poem?

Tags: poetry, meter

I was wondering how enjambment can be used to improve the rhythm in poetry.  I have seen some innovative uses of it by e.e. cummings, such as by breaking a word and writing the ending on the next line. Example:

> A. me ri
>   Ka, my mother la
>   nd, land of the bra
>   ve.....

I am looking for other ways enjambment is used to make the beat come through.

Comment: This is a good question, but I think for *this* site it should be angled slightly more towards "how is enjambment used in poetry" rather than "how can I use enjambment when writing poetry". The experts on [literature.se] can tell you about existing literature, while those on [writing.se] can advise you on creating your own. I've edited your question slightly to angle it more clearly into this site's scope; hope you don't mind.

Comment: I am asking not how to use enjambment in general. You can see from my example I know that already. What I ask is specifically using it to improve the rhythm of a poem just like we order stressed and unstressed syllables one way or the other to get rhyme. I saw example of cummins use of it to that end and I am asking whether someone may have other ways to use it in the same regard.

Comment: Yep, of course. I meant in my previous comment "how is enjambment used to enhance rhythm in poetry" vs "how can I use enjambment to enhance rhythm when writing poetry". Just shortened it a bit to make my comment flow more easily :-)

Comment: https://literarydevices.net/enjambment/